# How to mount USB device using jmtpfs on Linux (Debian 9)?

Tags: linux, debian, usb, android, mtp

Device Information `Settings -> System -> About device`

```
SAMSUNG-SM-G900R4, Android version 6.0.1
```

Computer System Information (Terminal command: `uname -a`)

```
Linux debian 4.9.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.110-3+deb9u4 (2018-08-21) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Mount USB device using jmtpfs

```
jmtpfs /media/SAMSUNG-SM-G900R4
```

ERROR-0

```
Device 0 (VID=04e8 and PID=6860) is a Samsung Galaxy models (MTP).
fuse: bad mount point `/media/vassil/SAMSUNG-SM-G900R4': Input/output error
```

ERROR-1

```
Device 0 (VID=04e8 and PID=6860) is a Samsung Galaxy models (MTP).
LIBMTP PANIC: Could not open session! (Return code 8195)
  Try to reset the device.
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'MtpErrorCantOpenDevice'
  what():  Can't open device
Aborted
```

TESTS
    Used different USB cables and tried various combinations of the following:

SAMSUNG-SM-G900R4
Unplug USB cable
Turn on Developer options: `Settings -> System -> About device -> tap "Build number" at least 7 times`
Set USB options: `Settings -> System -> Developer options -> USB debugging: ON, USB configuration: MTP (Media Transfer Protocol)`
Restart device
Plug USB cable

Computer
Restart Computer
Mount device: `jmtpfs /media/SAMSUNG-SM-G900R4`

SAMSUNG-SM-G900R4
If message `Allow access to device data appears`, then Tap `ALLOW`.

Computer
Check if you can access device directory: `cd /media/SAMSUNG-SM-G900R4; ls`

RESULTS
ERROR-0 is displayed, ERROR-1 is displayed, device directory is accessible with some frequencies.

Comment: That suggested duplicate was self-answered, and no points made.

Comment: It appears to be the same person asking both questions. Vassil, are you attempting to reopen your previous version of this question, or is this supposed to be a new variation that's distinct from the previous one?

Comment: @JeffSchaller - definitely not a variation, it's the same (identical) self-answered question, by the same person.

Comment: @JeffSchaller Yes, I'm trying to reopen previous version of question. Suggested edits were made and it was still closed.

Answer (score 2):

### **PERFORM EVERY STEP IN THE SPECIFIED ORDER**

SAMSUNG-SM-G900R4

1. Turn on Developer options: `Settings -> System -> About device -> tap "Build number" at least 7 times`
2. Set USB options: `Settings -> System -> Developer options -> USB debugging: ON, USB configuration: MTP (Media Transfer Protocol)`
3. Restart device

Computer

4. Mount device: `jmtpfs /media/SAMSUNG-SM-G900R4`

SAMSUNG-SM-G900R4

5. If message `Allow access to device data` appears, then Tap `ALLOW`.

Computer

6. Unmount device: `umount /media/SAMSUNG-SM-G900R4`
7. Mount device: `jmtpfs /media/SAMSUNG-SM-G900R4`
8. Check if you can access device directory: `cd /media/SAMSUNG-SM-G900R4; ls`

Comment: How do steps 1 and 2 help?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a process that worked for me, though it is brittle.

Keep in mind: once you do the process successfully, and unmount, then you will need to un-plug/re-plug the USB cable to start again. Otherwise, you will get the `Restart device` message, forever.

So, here we go:

1. Plug in your device
2. Run `jmtpfs mydir -f -o auto_unmount`

   - Note: `-f` causes it to run in "foreground" mode, not a daemon.
3. You will get a pop-up on your device, asking for permission. Click 'Accept'.

   - Note: during this period, for me, the target directory will have garbage permissions (shows as `?????` in `ls`) and be un-readable.
   - After you accept, it will still be un-readable. So now, we need to:
4. Kill the `jmtpfs` process, with `Ctrl-C`.
5. Run it again, this time you can use plain `jmtpfs mydir` (if you want)
6. Now, the directory should be usable!
7. Later, unmount with `fusermount -u`.

   - Note: as mentioned, un-mounting will permanently make it stop working, for this session. To re-start, you need to un-plug/re-plug the cable, and start at step 1, above.